# max_pool_with_argmax on CPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am currently trying to implement deconvolutional layers with `tensorflow`. To do this, I need to get the values along with the indices of the max pooling operation. `tensorflow` provides `max_pool_with_argmax` but it seems that this function is only available on GPU while I am using the CPU.

I am thus wondering whether there is a way to get such indices but with the CPU only?

Comment: I would also like to get it to work on CPU. Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: No, I did not find any solution to get it work on a CPU.